# Django/JavaScript: passing hidden variables to a page with window.location.href?

Tags: javascript, django

Apologies if this question is a bit convoluted.

I want a Django page to display a banner message *sometimes*. Sometimes the user will arrive via `window.location.href`, and then I would like the banner to display, with a message determined by the action the user just performed.

Details:

- I have a site-wide javascript listener that listens for scanner input (which presents as keyboard input).
- When it triggers, using jQuery I return or check out the item, dependent on its state. I do this via an Ajax POST request.
- Then I immediately take the user to the item's page on my site. I do this by setting `window.location.href` to the item's page, inside the response handler of the POST request. The item shows as available or checked out, but I want to show the user another message too...
- ...I want to show a banner saying 'Item checked out' or 'Item returned'.

The last item is where I'm having problems: how do I 'tell' the item page what message to show, and when to show a message at all? People will also arrive at item pages not via the scanner.

- I could set GET parameters (`?t=checked_out` or `?t=returned`) but that feels messy.
- I could use cookies but that feels even messier.
- If I POST to the item page (which also feels wrong) with a `t=checked_out` parameter, wouldn't it be good Django practice to then redirect somewhere else, rather than display the page?

Perhaps I'm just too hung up on the last point.

Anyway, the basic question is: How best can I pass hidden variables to a page via `window.location.href`?

Thanks for your help. I have the feeling there's something fundamental that I've yet to learn here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do an AJAX request at all for step 2/3? 
You asynchronously POST, then redirect.

Can you do a normal POST with info about whatever the javascript did, add some message in your session in the django backend (and have the item view load it), and do a server redirect to the item page?

The django way would definitely be to do it in `django` sessions.

If you must, your method should be possible anyways:

1. pass extra bits of information TO django in your ajax post
2. set your "hidden variabes" to the django session (`request.session['myvar'] =  'ajax_posted_stuff'`)
3. javascript redirect (but seriously, it would be best to have the server redirect)
4. pull "hidden variables" from the django session (`ajax_posted_stuff = request.session['myvar']`)

Example:

```
def ajax_view(request):
    if successful_response():
        request.session['show_banner'] = True
        return JSON # or whatever you were doing before

def item_view(request):
    context = {}
    if request.session.get('show_banner'):
        context['show_banner'] = request.session.pop('show_banner') 

    return render_to_response("mytemplate.html", context)

# item.html
{% if show_banner %}
    <h1>Banner shown!</h1>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: When you say 'asynchronously POST, then redirect' do you mean redirect inside the Django view? I suspect you're right, but how do I implement that? Currently I'm using `$.post` to a method in `views.py` that returns JSON to indicate success or failure - should it `HttpResponseRedirect` instead, and what jQuery call should I use to post? Thanks....

Comment: If you don't want a page reload on failure, I understand. In that case, your javascript method may be correct. It still doesn't stop you from using the session (much cleaner and the django way) though! Set the session variable upon successful POST on the django side, do your js redirect as usual, but in your Item view, have the view return some variables into the template "Show banner" or not, or what have you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think using a cookie would be messy? I'd say go for cookies if you can. You can read cookies from `window.document.cookie`.

As an alternative to cookies, the cleanest solution could be to use the URL hash:

```
http://example.com/page#co
```

You can easily check for the presence of the hash with `window.location.hash`.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the hash method because I'd like to hide the banner if someone refreshes the page...

Comment: You can remove the hash upon first load but that is filthy!

Comment: @Yuji: Why? The hash can be used as simple state storage and messing around with it absolutely has no bearing on cleanliness. If you change the hash on page load, the user probably even time to notice it.

Comment: @Ates Goral, I'm just against using javascript to check for a hash and then inject content (the second uh oh) if you can avoid it. Also the OP was asking about django best practice so that's where my comment came from.

Comment: @Yuji: By all means, if there's a proper Django alternative to this, that should be used. But, checking the hash with JavaScript to inject content is not an "uh-oh" at all: It is in fact how most modern websites do things nowadays (see Twitter for example).

Comment: I'm also not a fan of hashes, see: http://www.isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs

Comment: @AP257: You should drop the general stigma that "hashes are bad" and embrace the use cases in which they're absolutely useful and good. It's how and when they are applied that counts. There are websites with content that should be easy to crawl and cache and whatnot; and there are websites which are Single Page Interface *applications* that rely on hashes.